# Mostrar que un archivo se cargó en el file input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código para subir información a mi sitio, pero cuando cargo el archivo **no me muestra** el preload de que el archivo está listo para ser enviado, solo el `input` se encoge un poco pero no me muestra una previsualización por lo menos del nombre del archivo que tiene precargado.

¿Alguna sugerencia para que me **muestre el nombre del archivo** una vez que lo cargue antes de darle submit? Supongo que debo realizarlo con JavaScript, actualmente estoy aprendiendo Vue.

Estoy haciendo esto (como muestro en este [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/felloz82/bqfharpx/1)):

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
  font: 1rem/1.5 "PT Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/wtf-forms.css" />

<label class="file">
  <input type="file" id="file" aria-label="File browser example">
  <span class="file-custom"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al parecer `wtf forms` utiliza un `<span class="file-custom></span>` para generar su propio aspecto para el `input` de tipo file.

Digamos que el `input` es completamente fantasma y `wtf forms` lo sobrescribe con su `span`.

En la documentación aclaran el porqué de esto. http://wtfforms.com/

> *Heads up! The custom file input is currently unable to update the
>   Choose file... text with the filename. Without JavaScript, this might
>   not be possible to change, but I'm open to ideas.*

Te dejo mi solución. Básicamente le he agregado una propiedad `data-after` al `span`, esta propiedad la esta escuchando la propiedad `content` del `CSS`, de tal manera que cuando cambia la propiedad `data-after` también cambiara la propiedad `content`.

Espero que esto solucione tu problema.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
          content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/wtf-forms.css">
    <style>
        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
            font: 1rem/1.5 "PT Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #5a5a5a;
        }

        .file-custom::after {
            content: attr(data-after);
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <label class="file">
        <input type="file"
               id="file"
               onchange="fileChoose(event,this)"
               aria-label="File browser example">
        <span class="file-custom"
              data-after="Choose file..."></span>
    </label>

</body>
<script>
    function fileChoose(event, element) {
        if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
            element.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('data-after', event.target.files[0].name);
        }
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Nos puedes compartir por favor la documentación.

Comment: @dnlb documentación de wtforms http://wtfforms.com/